# Some tray icons disappear after shutdown overlay

Tags: gnome, 16.04, icons, lts, system-tray

I just installed and updated Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on my desktop PC.

If I click on the power button (top right icon on the desktop), then I click the larger power icon, then I cancel the operation, some of the tray icons (Skype, Dropbox and OwnCloud in my setup) become transparent. They are still in the tray, but you can't see the icons.

You can check a picture:

[image]

and a video of this behaviour from this link:

https://youtu.be/8DKmhQGFWJE

Any suggestion? Is it a bug? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Can anybody confirm if it happens only in my setup? I'm using NVIDIA binary driver version 361.42.

Comment: If I log out and then log in I can see the icons again.

Comment: I just tried to do the same on a laptop (Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS not updated since 10 days) and I can notice the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I restart the shell the icons come back, to do so:

press alt + f2

type "r" without quotes

hit enter

This is not a solution but a quick workaround. I believe it affects the icons of all the programs that depend on QT.

I opened a bug report and this is the address: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1594550

If you have this problem subscribe to the bug.