# Tray icons dissapear after screen lock

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 20.04, icons, system-tray

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, Nvidia video, and had an issue lately, tray icons for some apps dissapear from top right corner.

Still unable to reproduce behavior, I must say it's work's computer and it has to remain turned on 24/7, when I leave my office I lock the screen and when i return in the mornings they have vanished. I assume it happens as a result of the screen lock during the nights.

Rebooting fixes the problem but i can't do that every morning.

Also tried workaround posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789306/some-tray-icons-disappear-after-shutdown-overlay), using alt+f2 and typing r bring back the icons.

Must say that icons are not there at all, no blank space, nothing, but daemons running in the back.